# How to lock/unlock a file across process?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, locking

Using C# running on mono on Linux, notice that below code works well on windows can lock a file across process but not on linux via mono (ubuntu 14.04)

```
new FileStream("myfile.lock",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.None);
```

research from internet, i should be able to do it with [advisory lock](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-file-locking-types/)

```
FileStream.Lock
```

however, it doesn`t work. tested with two processes on ubuntu 14.04, both of them can execute "FileStream.Lock(0, int.MaxValue)". i would expect the later one will fail with exception per [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs#L862).

anyone know is there any solution?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what do you mean(?) as with an "advisory lock" any other process can update the file (given that is has security access to it). FYI: `FileStream.Lock` (via Mono) uses `fcntl`'s `F_SETLK`

Comment: @SushiHangover, i updated my question to have more details about the "does not work".  I tested with two process and both of them try to execute "FileStream.Lock", i was expecting one of them should throw error but didn`t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get help from mono mail list "http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/File-Locking-td4663839.html"

below is the answer quote from "Edward Ned Harvey (mono)"

> Kinda sorta. The underlying issue is that OSX, Linux, and Windows all
>   have different underlying file locking constructs, and then of course,
>   there's some variability about even *which* filesystem is being used.
>   I didn't thoroughly figure out all the answers for every OS or
>   filesystem, and I don't know under which situations this will be good
>   enough, but this is what I ended up using, works under the conditions
>   we needed it to work:

```
using (var foo = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)) { // must include Write access in order to lock file 
    foo.Lock(0, 0); // 0,0 has special meaning to lock entire file regardless of length 
}
```

> For windows, simply specifying the FileAccess and FileShare is good
>   enough. For linux, at least ext4, files are concurrently readable
>   regardless of what you specify for FileAccess and FileShare. The
>   Lock() method does something of a soft-lock. It's not enforced by the
>   OS, but at least all the situations we tried, other client apps honor
>   the lock. Didn't look into it any deeper.

Comment: If the process with the lock was to exit abnormally, would that release the lock on mono linux?

Comment: Yes, it releases the lock on mono linux.