# IPC between .NET 5 Preview and native C applications on linux - Synchronization

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, ipc, .net-5

I am looking at IPC between .NET and C on Linux.
I have managed to get some shared memory working using:

C     shm_open and mmap
C#    MemoryMappedFile

I need a mechanism though to be able to synchronize the changes between my .NET application and the C application and i cannot find a way to have a shared lock mechanism.

I have looked at named semaphores (but this is not supported on linux in .NET).
I have looked at named Mutex (but this is not supported in C on linux).
I have looked at creating a shared memory area for a phtread_mutex_t object in C on linux which works but i have no way to map that to anything in the .NET environment.

Does anyone know of a way I can do this or maybe get the pthread_mutex_t method working?

Comment: Maybe locking files could help you

Comment: Any chance you could explain or show a link on how that would work please?

Comment: Have you tried named muteness? Lock mechanisms are offered by the OS itself, not the language. Mutexes are OS constructs, and the behaviour between OSs can be different. `pthreads` is NOT cross-platform, nor a C standard, with different behaviour in Macs. C11 added [threads.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) but the *actual* behaviour can be different, which is why .NET Core [uses pthread robust mutexes on Linux, file locks on Mac](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/5211#issuecomment-620113032)

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, I am not quite sure what you are saying here. i have read through that link that you have provided. If pthread mutexes are used on Linux then how to I get the Mutex to be shared between my Dotnet application and the C application? When you create a pthread mutex in C there is no name assigned to it. The only way I have been able to get a name associated with it is to create some shared memory and put the pthread mutex and the name into shared memory. My issue is then on the dotnet program how to map a pthread_mutex_t structure to a dotnet structure to access through shared mem.

Comment: Then i have the issue of being able to lock using that structure. If you know any more than that I would appreciate anything you have. Thanks.

Comment: from the C code, you could use the flock() syscall as nanu_nana pointed out. Look up the man page (man 2 flock). I haven't used Mono or dot net on linux, but I believe this link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35463999/5639126